# Questions for anyone who has used Sun Type 7 keyboards

Tags: keyboard

So I noticed that Oracle is still selling [Sun Type 7](https://shop.sun.com/store/productsa/4ea491eb-44dd-11da-ac39-080020a9ed93?intcmp=soc) keyboard and mouse packages.  I was thinking of buying one for a Linux box at my house so I had easy access to some of the extra keys such as Compose and Alt-GR.  I have some questions though before I do for anyone who has used these -- it's been a very long time since I've used an actual Sun keyboard.

1. They show that both a PC and UNIX layout is available.  Unfortunately, I cannot find anywhere a clear picture of both layouts to determine the difference.  Can anyone post pictures of the 2 different layouts for me to take a look at?
2. I don't remember what some of the "Solaris shortcut" keys do, like Props, Front, Stop, and Again.  Are these vestiges from OpenWindows?  Do they have any usage on a modern Solaris like OpenSolaris running Gnome? Do they automatically map to anything useful on Linux, or am I going to have to map them myself to something with XModMap?
3. When I last used a Sun keyboard, I remember it having a rather mushy feel to it, so I am wondering if any touch typists could weigh in on whether this keyboard "feels nice" for day to day touch typing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'll go ahead and answer question #1 myself, as I finally located some crude layouts for the Sun keyboards.

**U.S. PC Keyboard Layout**

[image]

**U.S. UNIX Layout**

[image]

Per the [page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19683-01/806-6642/new-357/index.html) I found these on, these are accurate up to Type 5c.  I'd still like a picture of the two if someone else could supply that.

Answer (score 1):

I am a touch typist and use the Sun Type 7 keyboard at work. The keys don't have a mushy feel, they are quite responsive and have a soft feel to it. Also the plastic used, I believe, is soft touch, so it feels nice to touch.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check of hardware keyboards shown in the gnome keyboard configurator shows Sun type 5/6 as a choice. If the Type 7 isn't dramatically different, I would guess the Solaris keys will be mapped to something useful.

If you don't like the way the keys mapped, I'd suggest using [xkeycaps](http://www.jwz.org/xkeycaps/), it's a more user friendly frontend that still spits out an .xmodmap file.

I have no clue about mushiness though, I haven't used a Sun keyboard in a long time.

Comment: Except for the Japanese layout, all the Type 7 layouts are identical to the Type 6 ones.