# What's the difference between a Sun Type 6 and Type 7 keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I'm thinking of connecting a Sun keyboard to a PC (preferably via USB). Doing research I found that the most recent keyboards appear to be the **Type 6** and **Type 7** keyboards.  What is the difference between them?

Comment: [Questions for anyone who has used Sun Type 7 keyboards](http://superuser.com/q/181109)

Comment: @DavidPostill I also read that question before asking. It says *nothing* about Type 6/7 differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have both. From a layout perspective, they are exactly the same. 
(I have both a Type 6 US layout, and a Type 7 US layout, I put them side by side to compose this reply and not make any mistakes).

From a design/construction, there are subtle differences, first of all the Sun Type 6 is GREY, the type 7 is all WHITE.
Second the Type 6 lower side (near your hands) ends with a curve. The Type 7 ends abruptly (more square, if you prefer).

And perhaps the most noticeable of all, the Type 7 sports a "Sun-Oracle" logo exactly in the middle (above F8) while the Type 6 had the traditional Sun Microsystems logo at the top-right corner.

The icing on the cake for the Type 7 is its internal USB hub, with two USB female ports at the top, which the Type 6 lacked.

Comment: "From a layout perspective, they are exactly the same."  Not according to the pictures posted by bahamat, which show different locations for backspace and backslash...  The type 7 has an Esc key to the left of the number one, with the tilde/backtick key being moved to the upper-right.

Comment: The Sun keyboards are available in two basic layouts for a particular language, the UNIX layout and the PC Layout. In bahamat's photos below, the top photo of the Sun Type 6 has the PC layout and, below, the Sun Type 7 has the UNIX layout. @aissacf is correct; the Type 6 and 7 keyboards with the UNIX layout are exactly the same and the Type 6 and 7 keyboards with the PC layout are also exactly the same. If requested, I can take photos of the keyboard I'm using at this very moment, a Sun Type 7 PC layout.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a photo of the Sun Type 6:

[image]

Here's a photo of the Sun Type 7 (this one is mine):

[image: * https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8RsW.jpg]